# How to use Parallel.ForEach with Grid View in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, parallel-processing

I had created an application to send bulk mail but my application is taking too much time to send all the emails. This was my code:

```
  foreach (GridViewRow grow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string Emails = grow.Cells[0].Text.Trim();

            string file = Server.MapPath("~/Mail.html");
            string mailbody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
            string to = Emails;
            string from = "xyz@gmail.com";
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);
            msg.Subject = "Auto Response Email";
            msg.Body = mailbody;
            msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;   
            System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@gmail.com", "password");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.Credentials = basicCredential;
            try
            {
                client.Send(msg);
                cnfrm.Text = "Email Sended Successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

So for it's solution I tied to use the Parallel.ForEach but I am finding myself unable to use it with GridView.

```
  Parallel.ForEach(GridView1.Rows, GridViewRow =>
        {

            string Emails = grow.Cells[0].Text.Trim();

            string file = Server.MapPath("~/Mail.html");
            string mailbody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
            string to = Emails;
            string from = "xyz@gmail.com";
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);
            msg.Subject = "Auto Response Email";
            msg.Body = mailbody;
            msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz689@gmail.com", "password");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.Credentials = basicCredential;
            try
            {
                client.Send(msg);
                cnfrm.Text = "Email Sended Successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        });
```

Could anyone tell me how I can use it!!

Comment: I suggest to extract the content in a non parallel manor and then use the parallel version to send the mails. Don't access UI-elements without special handling from different threads!

Comment: Hey Sprinter252, could you please provide me an example for same!!

Comment: Trying to generate emails directly from the UI elements is not a good choice. You should use the same source you use to generate the GridView

Comment: See the answer of Chris L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can access the Gridview rows like that with multiple threads, extract the text in your main thread then use foreach. Also take a look at [`Partitioner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd422138.aspx) to use with `ForEach`

Here's an example of how it might look:

```
var emailtext = new List<string>()
foreach (GridViewRow grow in GridView1.Rows)
{
        emailtext.Add(grow.Cells[0].Text.Trim());
}

//split and load balance the List
Partitioner<string> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(emailtext, true); 
Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, mailtext =>
{
    //your email sending code here
    //NB: 'mailtext' is your string to send
}
```

**Note:** Most mail providers limit the number of emails you send per session or per hour, so you may need to consider this in your application.